# Python - Insert HTML tag into string

Tags: html, python-3.x

I'd like to insert an HTML tag into a Python string, but I am having some difficulties.

I've tried many different things with the {}, but I can't get it right, so I'm just going to put here my first attempt:

```
body = """
  Dear sender,

  Please find below the link of the report {}.
  
  <a href="{}">{}</a>

  As usual this report was generated automatically and was not validated afterwards.
  Any question or issue regarding this report should be addressed to x.

  Regards,
  Analytics Team
  """.format(report, ds_link, report)
```

This is not working and I realize it's probably because the href part is embedded into the string and shouldn't. I've already tried to get around this by doing string concatenation with that part, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: What's the output you expect vs what you get? At least from what I executed locally everything looks okay

Comment: Hi @AlejandroAristizábal. Thanks for the comment.
What I would like is to have the report name in the place of "<a href="{}">{}</a>" as an hypelink to the datastudio report.
What I have as of now is 

"(...) link of the report xxx.
  
  <a href="{}"><actual URL to the report></a>

(...) ". So my final goal is to not have  <a href="{}"><actual URL to the report></a>, but to have xxx as an hyperlink.